# How to send a Facebook App Notification via the Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, urllib2, urllib

I'd like my Facebook canvas app to send an [App Notification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) to a user's friend when they interact with the app.  Here is my server-side code (using App Engine and urllib).  `conf.FACEBOOK_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` is an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/) which I got by making a single call to the Graph API and then hardcoding the returned value, as explained in the link.  The app access token looks something like:

```
426547656256546|4fhe34FJdeV3WvfF6SNfehs7GfW
```

This isn't my actual token: I've substituted numbers for other numbers, capital letters for other capital letters, etc, so you can see the format.

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+friendID+'/notifications'
values = {'access_token' : conf.FACEBOOK_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          'href' : 'http://localhost:8080/', 
          'template' : '@['+userID+'] says hi.'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

`urlopen` gives the errors:

```
WARNING  Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
ERROR    HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

What do I need to correct in this code to successfully send an app notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App notifications can only be send from Canvas apps.  My app was set to `Website with Facebook  Login` in the Facebook settings, which doesn't allow notifications.  To solve the problem, I just checked `App on Facebook` in addition to `Website with Facebook Login` (though I believe it works with only `App on Facebook` as well) and specified a canvas URL.